# RecyclerView Color Change Deletion Bug

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-recyclerview

[Assignments Pre-Deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dibDl.png)

[After Deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72iJD.png)

I am creating a school planner app and to display the assignments I am reading from a room database into a RecyclerView. Each item row has the assignment name, type, and due date, as well as a delete button. Each item row's background turns Red if the assignment is overdue, Green if the assignment is due today, and the default color if the assignment is due in the future (past today). The bug I am running into happens when an assignment that is a color(red or green) is on top of an assignment with a different color. When the assignment that is colored is deleted, the assignment below is changed to the color of the previously deleted assignment. If the app is restarted or another activity is started and then the RecyclerView is pulled up again, the assignment is back to its correct color.

[Update] Don't know whether or not this affects the issue but my `item_row.xml` file for the `RecyclerView` does not use `CardView`

Here is the method where I change the color:

````
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Fetching the database table at the current position from database list
        AssignmentTable assignmentTable = assignmentList.get(position);
        //Instantiating the views
        String due = "Due: "+assignmentTable.dueDate;
        String type = assignmentTable.type;
        holder.txtItemName.setText(assignmentTable.name);
        holder.txtItemDate.setText(due);
        holder.txtItemType.setText(type);
        //Setting the checkboxes to their saved state
        if(assignmentTable.isCompleted == true){
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        //Fetching current due date and parsing
        Date currentDate = getCurrentDate();
        String dueDateAsString = assignmentTable.dueDate;
        Date dueDateOfCurrentAssignment = parseDate(dueDateAsString);
        //changing the background color programmatically
        if(currentDate.equals(dueDateOfCurrentAssignment)){
            holder.txtItemDate.setText("Due: Today"); //changes due date
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#228b22")); // changes color to green
            Log.d("REACHED", "GREEN COLOR");
        }
        if(dueDateOfCurrentAssignment.before(currentDate)){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8b0000")); // turns the background red
            holder.txtItemDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7a7a")); // turns text bright red
            Log.d("REACHED", "RED COLOR");
        }
        //Logging fields
        String assignment = "\nName: " + assignmentTable.name + "\nDue Date: " + assignmentTable.dueDate 
           + "\nType: " + assignmentTable.type + "\nCompleted: " + assignmentTable.isCompleted;
        Log.d("AT END OF ONBIND", "\n" + assignment);

    }```

and here is the method called on the delete buttons onClick.
````

````
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Getting database table at the specified position to delete
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        AssignmentTable assignmentTable = assignmentList.get(position);
        ItemRepository itemRepository = new ItemRepository(view.getContext());
        //Deleting from the database
        itemRepository.deleteItem(assignmentTable);
        itemRepository.updateItem(assignmentTable);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Deleted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }```
````

Comment: Kindly post some screenshots of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue! Turns out I just needed to add an extra else statement wihtin the `OnBindViewHolder();` method

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Fetching the database table at the current position from database list
    AssignmentTable assignmentTable = assignmentList.get(position);
    //Instantiating the views
    String due = "Due: "+assignmentTable.dueDate;
    String type = assignmentTable.type;
    holder.txtItemName.setText(assignmentTable.name);
    holder.txtItemDate.setText(due);
    holder.txtItemType.setText(type);
    //Setting the checkboxes to their saved state
    if(assignmentTable.isCompleted == true){
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
    //Fetching current due date and parsing
    Date currentDate = getCurrentDate();
    String dueDateAsString = assignmentTable.dueDate;
    Date dueDateOfCurrentAssignment = parseDate(dueDateAsString);
    //changing the background color programmatically
    if(currentDate.equals(dueDateOfCurrentAssignment)){
        holder.txtItemDate.setText("Due: Today"); //changes due date
        holder.txtItemDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#228b22")); // changes color to green
        Log.d("REACHED", assignmentTable.name + " GREEN COLOR");
    }else if(dueDateOfCurrentAssignment.before(currentDate)){
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8b0000")); // turns the background red
        holder.txtItemDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7a7a")); // turns text bright red
        Log.d("REACHED", assignmentTable.name + " RED COLOR");
    }else{
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#191970"));
        holder.txtItemDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        Log.d("REACHED", assignmentTable.name + " REGULAR BACKGROUND");
    }
    //Logging fields
    String assignment = "\nName: " + assignmentTable.name + "\nDue Date: " + assignmentTable.dueDate + "\nType: " +
            assignmentTable.type + "\nCompleted: " + assignmentTable.isCompleted;
    Log.d("AT END OF ONBIND", "\n" + assignment);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in your delete method. You should also call `notifyItemRemoved(position)`.

Here is what documentation says about it:

> Notify any registered observers that the item previously located at position has been removed from the data set.

Hope it works out!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work

Comment: How are you determining the size of recyclerview? What's your code inside getItemCount?

Comment: While removing the item, did you remove it from the list (from which you are getting the tables)?

Comment: `@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return assignmentList.size();
    }`  This is my code inside getItemCount

Comment: I added  `assignmentList.remove(position);`  to the `onClick();` but this didn't help

Comment: Then I'm afraid that I'm out of anymore suggestions. Although, this doesn't answer your question but still- you should have your if statements joined with if and elseif not 2 separate if.